# Lit / LitElement ReactiveElement static properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element, lit

Lit uses this [reactive element class](https://github.com/lit/lit/blob/main/packages/reactive-element/src/reactive-element.ts#L371), which each of my web components extends. I can't quite get my head around why static properties such as
`elementProperties` are NOT the same on all web components that extend the Lit base class.

[See example here](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=W3sibmFtZSI6InNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy50cyIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJpbXBvcnQge2h0bWwsIGNzcywgTGl0RWxlbWVudCwgUmVhY3RpdmVFbGVtZW50fSBmcm9tICdsaXQnO1xuaW1wb3J0IHtjdXN0b21FbGVtZW50LCBwcm9wZXJ0eX0gZnJvbSAnbGl0L2RlY29yYXRvcnMuanMnO1xuXG5AY3VzdG9tRWxlbWVudCgnc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nJylcbmV4cG9ydCBjbGFzcyBTaW1wbGVHcmVldGluZyBleHRlbmRzIExpdEVsZW1lbnQge1xuICBzdGF0aWMgc3R5bGVzID0gY3NzYHAgeyBjb2xvcjogYmx1ZSB9YDtcblxuICBAcHJvcGVydHkoKVxuICBuYW1lID0gJ1NvbWVib2R5JztcblxuICByZW5kZXIoKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIGh0bWxgPHA-UHJvcHM6ICR7QXJyYXkuZnJvbSgodGhpcy5jb25zdHJ1Y3RvciBhcyB0eXBlb2YgUmVhY3RpdmVFbGVtZW50KS5lbGVtZW50UHJvcGVydGllcy5rZXlzKCkpfSE8L3A-YDtcbiAgfVxuICBcbn1cblxuXG5AY3VzdG9tRWxlbWVudCgnc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLTInKVxuZXhwb3J0IGNsYXNzIFNpbXBsZUdyZWV0aW5nMiBleHRlbmRzIExpdEVsZW1lbnQge1xuICBzdGF0aWMgc3R5bGVzID0gY3NzYHAgeyBjb2xvcjogYmx1ZSB9YDtcblxuICBAcHJvcGVydHkoKVxuICBzaXplID0gJ3NtYWxsJztcblxuICByZW5kZXIoKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIGh0bWxgPHA-UHJvcHM6ICR7QXJyYXkuZnJvbSgodGhpcy5jb25zdHJ1Y3RvciBhcyB0eXBlb2YgUmVhY3RpdmVFbGVtZW50KS5lbGVtZW50UHJvcGVydGllcy5rZXlzKCkpfSE8L3A-YDtcbiAgfVxuICBcbn0ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZyBuYW1lPVwiV29ybGRcIj48L3NpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZz5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy0yPjwvc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLTI-XG48L2JvZHk-XG4ifV0)

Why is the static property different on these two classes? I thought static properties were set on the class itself, in this case ReactiveElement. But this doesn't seem to be the case here. I would expect the `elementProperties` to be the same and work similar to [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgKgU0gbwCgFjJgIBLWBAC22WQHsEBeBAO2wHcEBZYABwAUASgDcBIiWABPABJ1GIhIWKrVsBmzANk2AHSMA5oMERq5MHo1boAV3gMoCNAgjT%202BgDMsuCML1aegYxSQQAXwJIiRQ0DAAxJ2wADwhsNgATDBxIZTCEfP5bMGp5YKUVNVVTc0trSCh7CEdnDDcPb19IAKDGPTBsCEEAIhBNACsGWyhhgBpXRuxQtUjo2PQEAFE2BBS0zOy-PLUikrLFYWOq4hqLK00GppaXds8fHP9AhQZ%20wZHehhzBa2JbiFZRCQEeqILxOVgcbiJESiApQh6IdIsdhcLZsZGo2F6U6lb7IgjpInFEnlUIEQlgGTnBhkikMuSk2lAA).

Can any one please tell me where i'm going wrong in my thinking?

Update:

OK recreated the behaviour with [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgKgU0gbwCgFjJgIBLWBAC22WQHsEBeBAO2wHcEBZYABwAUASgDcBIiWABPABJ1GIhIWKrVsBmzANk2AHSMA5oMERq5MHo1boAV3gMoCNAgjT%202BgDMsuCML1aegYxSQQAX0kw0goqKFxsCABJCCUVNTMLQIUmVg5uPiFQtVdzSyDGPTBEwQAiaQZagBpXKFtsYuJwhAJIghQ0DAAxJ2wADwhsNgATDBxIZTCEflswanlgtKW1UzKrTUg2hycXNw9vX0gAioYqmtqQTQArBlsoZtb2zq7eiQH0BAAUTYCHGkxmcz8izUKzWG0UwmhJWIuyy1kO9ggjmcGDOnh88382WCd1StRuHzsHXEakifX6B0QXiceS4CBGIlEPQZNlBINZ3GBnO5zL0sPWOU5BCmYtWEs2oQIIz08WqyVSYhFUCqMnhDClMrAuslYiAA). So I think I need to research how inheritance and static properties work in JS.

Answer (score 0):

So what I think is happening is;

elementProperties are set inside a static method called [finalize](https://github.com/lit/lit/blob/main/packages/reactive-element/src/reactive-element.ts#L570)

When finalise is called `this` refers to the component's class not the reactive element class. So `SimpleGreeting.elementProperties` not `ReactiveElement.elementProperties`.

Although the `ReactiveElement.elementProperties` exists in the prototype chain of `SimpleGreeting`.`Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(SimpleGreeting)).elementProperties`. Because we have set elementProperties on the SimpleGreeting property itself does not refer to `ReactiveElement.elementProperties` futher up the prototype chain.